# How do you get from a model to a set of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, soft-question, dynamical-systems

Consider the case of a predator-prey system. Morally speaking, there should be a way to take a model (which is to say, a complete description of a predator-prey dynamics which can be executed by a computer program) and by inspecting it derive the Lotka-Volterra Equations, or any other kind of differential equation, logistic map, or quantitative relationship.

Both models and differential equations are descriptions of system, and because the former is more comprehensive and the latter just a fragment, there must be a way, morally speaking, to derive the latter by inspecting the former.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by morally speaking. Also, I suppose you mean specifically those models that happen to correspond to differential equations (not all models do)? Or are you looking for some more general idea?

Comment: @user20672 any parameter of a model that changes over time should be describable by a differential equation. Maybe it won't have a closed form or an expression in terms of elementary arithmetical functions, but it should have a differential equation. That's also what I mean by "morally speaking."

Comment: If the system evolves continuously, yes. But discrete systems won't have a differential equation in the traditional sense. What I was getting at though, is that the term `model` encompasses more than dynamical systems. Discrete distributions are often used as mathematical models, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical models are all about assumptions. Different assumptions will produce different mathematical models. In general, models that relate the rates of change of different quantities will have a natural representation as differential equations. The only commonality between these sorts of mathematical models and how one arrives at them, in my opinion, is that one makes an assumption about how some rate of change in the system behaves. This is then described by a differential equation.

However, how one arrives at those models can be convoluted, and I'm not sure there is a definitive method for deriving a system of differential equations for any phenomenon that you might want to model. For example, compare the derivation of the Lotka-Volterra equations with those of continuum mechanics. The former starts with a simple assumption about how predator/prey populations affect population growth. Continuum mechanics, on the other hand, requires assumptions about conservation and, additionally, constitutive behavior to close the system (make it solvable). It's not clear to me that these derivations are similar in any way other than that both *eventually* reduce to expressions of instantaneous change.